# I keep getting the error message, "The type LinkedStackInteger<T> must implement the inherited abstract method IStack<T>.push(T)"

Tags: java

```
package tool;

public class LinkedStackInteger<T> implements IStack<T>{
    
    class Node {
        T number;
        Node next;
        Node top;

        Node(T number){
            this.number = number;
            this.next = null;
        }

        Node(T number, Node tail){
            this.number = number;
            this.next = tail;
        }
// for this part I had to make it public void but my peers say it should just be public

        public void LinkedStackInteger(){
            top = null;
        }
//Tried to override the 4 functions but the error doesn't disappear 
   
        @Override
        public T peek() {
            if (top == null){
                return null;
            }
            return top.number;
        }

        @Override
        public T pop(){
            if (top == null){
                return null;
            }
            T val = peek();
            top = top.next;
            return val;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty(){
            return top == null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean push (T val)){
            top = new Node(val, top);
            return true;
        }
    

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you've defined the methods push, etc. inside the `Node` class instead of inside the `LinkedStackInteger` class. You've basically put the closing brace of `Node` in the wrong place (too far down).

Also, this is the reason you had to write `public void LinkedStackInteger()` when your colleagues said it should be `public LinkedStackInteger()` - because you were intending it to be a constructor, but since it's in the wrong place (`Node` instead of `LinkedStackInteger`) it's not actually a constructor.